# Getting the bound data object of pressed table row - getBindingContext() returns undefeind

Tags: sapui5

In SAP UI5, I try to get the data object (in my controller) that is bound to a table row when the user presses it. My view is defined in XML, and my controller is in JS of course.

I have checked [How to get content of a row in sap.m.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599188/how-to-get-content-of-a-row-in-sap-m-table) already but it doesn't work for me, or something is missing.

My view (the relevant part):

```xml
<Panel>
  <Table id="lineItemList" items="{
    path: 'statusJobs>/jobs',
    sorter: {
      path: 'start',
      descending: true
    }
  }">
  <headerToolbar>
    <!-- ... -->
  </headerToolbar>
  <columns>
    <Column hAlign="Left" vAlign="Middle">
      <Label text="Job" />
    </Column>
    <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
      <Label text="Start" />
    </Column>
    <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
      <Label text="End" />
    </Column>
    <Column hAlign="Right" vAlign="Middle">
      <Label text="Success" />
    </Column>
  </columns>
  <ColumnListItem
    type="Navigation"
    press=".handleLineItemPress"
  >
    <Text text="{statusJobs>job}" />
    <Text text="{
      path: 'statusJobs>start',
      formatter:'util.Formatter.Date'}"
    />
    <Text text="{
      path: 'statusJobs>end',
      formatter: 'util.Formatter.Date'}"
    />
    <Text text="{statusJobs>status}"/>
  </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

The relevant part here is obviously:

```xml
<ColumnListItem
  type="Navigation"
  press=".handleLineItemPress"
>
```

And in my controller, I have this:

```js
handleLineItemPress: function(evt) {
  console.log('evt.getSource: ' + evt.getSource());
  console.log('evt.getBindingContext: ' + evt.getSource().getBindingContext());
}
```

which logs as follows:

> evt.getSource: Element sap.m.ColumnListItem#__item11-StatusJobs--lineItemList-0
>   evt.getBindingContext: undefined

`evt.getSource` returns the ColumnListItem, so of course from there, I could use the object hierarchy and fetch the text of a cell, like:

```js
evt.getSource().getCells()[0].getText();
```

But this does not seem to be the right way and especially does not give the the entire object nor its unique ID, which I happen to not display in the table.

I am somehow missing the connection back to my data model, that I had bound earlier in the code, in the `<Table>` item, as follows:

```
items="{
  path: 'statusJobs>/jobs',
  sorter: {
    path: 'start',
    descending: true
  }
}"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the binding context of clicked item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556515/how-to-get-the-binding-context-of-clicked-item)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I hate to say it, but I have had the same issue, and it took me quite some time to find the cause...

It's all related to the use of named models, in your case `statusJobs`.

If you want to retrieve the binding context for items bound to a named attribute, for some reason (honestly, I can't think of any) you also have to specify the named model:

```
evt.getSource().getBindingContext("statusJobs");
```

will return the correct binding context.

Thus, to retrieve the actual object bound to the pressed line item, you could then use:

```
var obj = evt.getSource().getBindingContext("statusJobs").getObject();
```

*Since a context can't be bound to more than one model (to my knowledge) I really don't understand why you need to specifically give the named model name as a parameter, but for now I guess we have to live with this behavior*